# SQL Server multiple many-to-many join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I currently have a one main table with multiple other tables associated with it via many-to-many joins (with join tables). The application using this database needs to have search functionality that will print out multiple rows matching specific criteria, including all the values in the join tables. The values from the join tables also need to be links that will enable a search for all other rows that match that value. I am trying to figure out how to do this without taxing the database.

Here is an example of the table structure

```
**Metrics (Main Table)** 
MetricID (pk) 
Metric

**Domains (ValueList Table)** 
DomainID (pk) 
Domain

**MetricsDomains (Join Table)** 
MetricsDomainsID (pk) 
MetricID (fk) 
DomainID (fk)

**MetricTypes (ValueList Table)** 
MetricTypeID (pk) 
MetricType

**MetricsMetricTypes (Join Table)** 
MetricMetricTypesID (pk) 
MetricID (fk) 
MetricTypeID (fk)

**Studies (ValueList Table)** 
StudyID (pk) 
Study

**MetricsStudies (Join Table)** 
MetricsStudiesID (pk) 
MetricID (fk) 
StudyID (fk)
```

When someone searches for a Metric by various criteria, they should get output in table format that looks something like this:

```
Metric1 | Description | Study1, Study2, Study3 | MetricType1, MetricType2 | Domain1, Domain2
Metric2 | Description | Study5, Study2, Study4 | MetricType2, MetricType3 | Domain5, Domain9
```

The Metric will be a link to the full description of the Metric. However, in addition, the Studies (ie., Study 1, Study 2, Study 3, etc.) and MetricTypes (MetricType1, Metric2, etc.) and Domains (Domain1, Domain 2, etc.) should also be links, that when clicked on, will perform a new search for all other metrics that contain that study, or type, or domain. This leads me to believe I will also need the primary key of the study, type, or domain, in addition to the text, in order to place in the href.

At any rate, considering one search could possibly return 20+ metrics, what I need to figure out is a good way to write an optimized query to return the results of the multiple many-to-many joins. I know that joining all of these tables in one query will generally result in a Cartesian product of all the joins, but I am not sure if there is another way to go about it. I have also read about a way I could return the many-to-many results as a comma-separated list in a field using a method like this:

```
SELECT m.MetricID, Description, 
    STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + s.Study
    FROM Studies s, Metrics_Studies ms 
    WHERE s.StudyID = ms.StudyID AND ms.MetricID = m.MetricID
    ORDER BY s.Study
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') as Study, 
FROM Metrics m 
WHERE Metric_PK = 13
```

However, I am not sure of the performance impact of this method, or whether it will really get me what I am looking for since I think I may need the primary keys of the Studies as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: should the last field in MetricsMetricTypes be MetricTypeID instead of DomainID?

Comment: In your joing tables (i.e. MetricsDomains), do you really need a separate PK (MetricsDomainsID), or could you make it a combination of the two FK? (MetricID, DomainID).  That would mean you can only have one of each combination, but that feels right anyway.

Comment: @Mark You're right. I've fixed it in the original question.

Comment: @Paul I could do that. There should only be one of each combination. Don't know if that affects the original problem though :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it first with your multi-joins - only then will you know whether the perofrmance is good enough.  As always you have to beware of premature optimisation.  Once you have your query running correctly against your normalised model, you can check the query plan, etc.  This may highlight that you need to flatten a few of your joins, if that's the case you probably will have to store the data in two different formats, one for reporting / one for searching, etc.  But 1st thing is to see if performance is actually acceptable out of the box.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So far, since I need to continue on this app, I've been using a variation of the subquery method that I posted above (although I eliminated the STUFF() function around it to save some database processing, since I can eliminate the leading comma through post-processing within the application). Is this what you are suggesting? So far, the query processing time hasn't even hit a hundredth of a second, so I don't think it will be an issue. I was just wondering if there was a cleaner/better way to go about it.

Comment: @Kirsen: Yes that's it - get something clean that works (and you understand).  Like you say, that allows you to continue the application.  Only then if you need, revisit to improve performance if needed.  As you develop the app, something else might trigger a change in the data model that either negates any optimisation you'd made or provides a far easier way to optimise the code.